# Passing json_encoded string with single quote

Tags: javascript, php, json

I'm trying to pass a json string to JS, but I'm having problems with the fact that sometimes, there's an apostrophe.

```
function GetHTML( $character )
{   
    $json = json_encode( $character );

    $html = '<div class="linkWindow">'; // links window
    $html .= '<div class="links">'; // links
    $html .= "<span onclick='LoadWeaponWindow(" . $json . ")'>WEAPON</span><br><br>";
    $html .= "<span onclick='LoadArmorWindow(" . $json . ")'>ARMOR</span><br><br>";
    $html .= '</div>'; // end links
    $html .= '</div>'; // end links window

    return $html;
}
```

At this point, $json has the following:

```
{"name":"Prayos Drakebane","server":"Sargatanas","lastSynced":"2017-11-27 06:42:01","id":1395894,"title":"Finder of False Gods","hp":31966,"mp":15480,"tp":1000,"strength":134,"dexterity":292,"vitality":1603,"intelligence":2343,"mind":219,"level":70,"eightBitImage":"\/images\/black_mage.png","job":"Black Mage","mainHand":"Palladium Staff","mainHandIcon":"https:\/\/img.finalfantasyxiv.com\/lds\/pc\/global\/images\/itemicon\/66\/661be0dedb391b0dc47e3d8adaec13936b6fc8b7.png?20171121","mainHandLink":"https:\/\/na.finalfantasyxiv.com\/lodestone\/playguide\/db\/item\/ddade11374b","head":"True Griffin Hat of Casting","headIcon":"https:\/\/img.finalfantasyxiv.com\/lds\/pc\/global\/images\/itemicon\/f5\/f53642ff6b75927a0697c61022f034257a0de23f.png?20171121","headLink":"https:\/\/na.finalfantasyxiv.com\/lodestone\/playguide\/db\/item\/fa1281f7e98","body":"Augmented Lost Allagan Coat of Casting","bodyIcon":"https:\/\/img.finalfantasyxiv.com\/lds\/pc\/global\/images\/itemicon\/7a\/7a0c7232f4d31e431b5a67478572913f95c63518.png?20171121","bodyLink":"https:\/\/na.finalfantasyxiv.com\/lodestone\/playguide\/db\/item\/c271ddd702d","hands":"Ivalician Enchanter's Gloves","handsIcon":"https:\/\/img.finalfantasyxiv.com\/lds\/pc\/global\/images\/itemicon\/a5\/a514dd4fd3c966246b4e05b3ac6e628f14a2fe56.png?20171121","handsLink":"https:\/\/na.finalfantasyxiv.com\/lodestone\/playguide\/db\/item\/b5259d4ef69","waist":"Ivalician Enchanter's Belt","waistIcon":"https:\/\/img.finalfantasyxiv.com\/lds\/pc\/global\/images\/itemicon\/90\/90a4d2a95b62c557c675a5363d2f8cacfda91067.png?20171121","waistLink":"https:\/\/na.finalfantasyxiv.com\/lodestone\/playguide\/db\/item\/c668efaf693","legs":"Indigo Ramie Skirt of Casting","legsIcon":"https:\/\/img.finalfantasyxiv.com\/lds\/pc\/global\/images\/itemicon\/e2\/e2227d544298e84bd3f936826fc0a0d6c4a934b4.png?20171121","legsLink":"https:\/\/na.finalfantasyxiv.com\/lodestone\/playguide\/db\/item\/46339edb3ec","feet":"True Griffin Sandals of Casting","feetIcon":"https:\/\/img.finalfantasyxiv.com\/lds\/pc\/global\/images\/itemicon\/d5\/d5d91e99b53f2722017ad6650c6bee68930d2c6b.png?20171121","feetLink":"https:\/\/na.finalfantasyxiv.com\/lodestone\/playguide\/db\/item\/fd90dc76e4a","necklace":"Torreya Choker of Casting","necklaceIcon":"https:\/\/img.finalfantasyxiv.com\/lds\/pc\/global\/images\/itemicon\/b8\/b8a1d3ef14debf3bf45b4a79e547653ab9b3626e.png?20171121","necklaceLink":"https:\/\/na.finalfantasyxiv.com\/lodestone\/playguide\/db\/item\/61e17c7186b","earrings":"Palladium Earring of Casting","earringsIcon":"https:\/\/img.finalfantasyxiv.com\/lds\/pc\/global\/images\/itemicon\/4e\/4e4e76d48639b077712e4635e3c0f39849753c25.png?20171121","earringsLink":"https:\/\/na.finalfantasyxiv.com\/lodestone\/playguide\/db\/item\/17c2574a8c9","bracelets":"Torreya Bracelet of Casting","braceletsIcon":"https:\/\/img.finalfantasyxiv.com\/lds\/pc\/global\/images\/itemicon\/0d\/0de0c69631533917a0f864e136f23b31d0c0e1ce.png?20171121","braceletsLink":"https:\/\/na.finalfantasyxiv.com\/lodestone\/playguide\/db\/item\/4644ad69a08","ring1":"Palladium Band of Casting","ring1Icon":"https:\/\/img.finalfantasyxiv.com\/lds\/pc\/global\/images\/itemicon\/2f\/2fa28cb0073b9df10f9867808f51fb10f920203f.png?20171121","ring1Link":"https:\/\/na.finalfantasyxiv.com\/lodestone\/playguide\/db\/item\/70ff3567828","ring2":"Palladium Band of Casting","ring2Icon":"https:\/\/img.finalfantasyxiv.com\/lds\/pc\/global\/images\/itemicon\/2f\/2fa28cb0073b9df10f9867808f51fb10f920203f.png?20171121","ring2Link":"https:\/\/na.finalfantasyxiv.com\/lodestone\/playguide\/db\/item\/70ff3567828"}
```

So my HTML looks like:

```
<span onclick='LoadWeaponWindow({"name":"Prayos Drakebane","server":"Sargatanas","lastSynced":"2017-11-27 06:42:01","id":1395894,"title":"Finder of False Gods","hp":31966,"mp":15480,"tp":1000,"strength":134,"dexterity":292,"vitality":1603,"intelligence":2343,"mind":219,"level":70,"eightBitImage":"\/images\/black_mage.png","job":"Black Mage","mainHand":"Palladium Staff","mainHandIcon":"https:\/\/img.finalfantasyxiv.com\/lds\/pc\/global\/images\/itemicon\/66\/661be0dedb391b0dc47e3d8adaec13936b6fc8b7.png?20171121","mainHandLink":"https:\/\/na.finalfantasyxiv.com\/lodestone\/playguide\/db\/item\/ddade11374b","head":"True Griffin Hat of Casting","headIcon":"https:\/\/img.finalfantasyxiv.com\/lds\/pc\/global\/images\/itemicon\/f5\/f53642ff6b75927a0697c61022f034257a0de23f.png?20171121","headLink":"https:\/\/na.finalfantasyxiv.com\/lodestone\/playguide\/db\/item\/fa1281f7e98","body":"Augmented Lost Allagan Coat of Casting","bodyIcon":"https:\/\/img.finalfantasyxiv.com\/lds\/pc\/global\/images\/itemicon\/7a\/7a0c7232f4d31e431b5a67478572913f95c63518.png?20171121","bodyLink":"https:\/\/na.finalfantasyxiv.com\/lodestone\/playguide\/db\/item\/c271ddd702d","hands":"Ivalician Enchanter's Gloves","handsIcon":"https:\/\/img.finalfantasyxiv.com\/lds\/pc\/global\/images\/itemicon\/a5\/a514dd4fd3c966246b4e05b3ac6e628f14a2fe56.png?20171121","handsLink":"https:\/\/na.finalfantasyxiv.com\/lodestone\/playguide\/db\/item\/b5259d4ef69","waist":"Ivalician Enchanter's Belt","waistIcon":"https:\/\/img.finalfantasyxiv.com\/lds\/pc\/global\/images\/itemicon\/90\/90a4d2a95b62c557c675a5363d2f8cacfda91067.png?20171121","waistLink":"https:\/\/na.finalfantasyxiv.com\/lodestone\/playguide\/db\/item\/c668efaf693","legs":"Indigo Ramie Skirt of Casting","legsIcon":"https:\/\/img.finalfantasyxiv.com\/lds\/pc\/global\/images\/itemicon\/e2\/e2227d544298e84bd3f936826fc0a0d6c4a934b4.png?20171121","legsLink":"https:\/\/na.finalfantasyxiv.com\/lodestone\/playguide\/db\/item\/46339edb3ec","feet":"True Griffin Sandals of Casting","feetIcon":"https:\/\/img.finalfantasyxiv.com\/lds\/pc\/global\/images\/itemicon\/d5\/d5d91e99b53f2722017ad6650c6bee68930d2c6b.png?20171121","feetLink":"https:\/\/na.finalfantasyxiv.com\/lodestone\/playguide\/db\/item\/fd90dc76e4a","necklace":"Torreya Choker of Casting","necklaceIcon":"https:\/\/img.finalfantasyxiv.com\/lds\/pc\/global\/images\/itemicon\/b8\/b8a1d3ef14debf3bf45b4a79e547653ab9b3626e.png?20171121","necklaceLink":"https:\/\/na.finalfantasyxiv.com\/lodestone\/playguide\/db\/item\/61e17c7186b","earrings":"Palladium Earring of Casting","earringsIcon":"https:\/\/img.finalfantasyxiv.com\/lds\/pc\/global\/images\/itemicon\/4e\/4e4e76d48639b077712e4635e3c0f39849753c25.png?20171121","earringsLink":"https:\/\/na.finalfantasyxiv.com\/lodestone\/playguide\/db\/item\/17c2574a8c9","bracelets":"Torreya Bracelet of Casting","braceletsIcon":"https:\/\/img.finalfantasyxiv.com\/lds\/pc\/global\/images\/itemicon\/0d\/0de0c69631533917a0f864e136f23b31d0c0e1ce.png?20171121","braceletsLink":"https:\/\/na.finalfantasyxiv.com\/lodestone\/playguide\/db\/item\/4644ad69a08","ring1":"Palladium Band of Casting","ring1Icon":"https:\/\/img.finalfantasyxiv.com\/lds\/pc\/global\/images\/itemicon\/2f\/2fa28cb0073b9df10f9867808f51fb10f920203f.png?20171121","ring1Link":"https:\/\/na.finalfantasyxiv.com\/lodestone\/playguide\/db\/item\/70ff3567828","ring2":"Palladium Band of Casting","ring2Icon":"https:\/\/img.finalfantasyxiv.com\/lds\/pc\/global\/images\/itemicon\/2f\/2fa28cb0073b9df10f9867808f51fb10f920203f.png?20171121","ring2Link":"https:\/\/na.finalfantasyxiv.com\/lodestone\/playguide\/db\/item\/70ff3567828"})'>WEAPON</span>
```

Now, in this instance, the "hands" and "waist" have an apostrophe, and it's returning an error onclick:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

I've tried running a str_replace:

```
$char = str_replace( "'", "\'", $json );
```

Which appears to have done it, but the error still shows. My question is, is how can I pass this string with the apostrophe into the JS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On server side, (on php code), you can do it in this way:

```
$json = json_encode(
   $character, 
   JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_AMP
);
```

It will do it for you

Answer (score 2):

You can escape by using `addslashes`

```
$html .= "<span onclick='LoadWeaponWindow(" . addslashes( $json ) . ")'>WEAPON</span><br><br>";
$html .= "<span onclick='LoadArmorWindow(" . addslashes( $json ) . ")'>ARMOR</span><br><br>";
```

Here is the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php